# Change href of a link jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

currently I have a textbox in which someone can type in a link, and then a link on the page next to the textbox should change it's href attribute to the text the user just typed in.

My javascript:

```
var LinkText = $("[id$=TextBox]").val();
    $("[id$=DocumentLink]").href = LinkText;
```

My HTML:

```
<a id ="DocumentLink" target = "_blank" href="http://www.currentlink.com/">Link to Document</a>
<input id="TextBox" type="text" /> `
```

Although LinkText is picked up as the string typed in the textbox, the second line of my javascript is not working as I want. The link stays as the currentlink.
I have jQuery 1.4.2 if that helps, I could be doing something that doesn't work with that maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a jQuery object you have to set the `attr`

```
$("[id$=DocumentLink]").attr("href", LinkText);
```

Or you can get the actual HTMLElement at the `0` index and call `.href` that way:

```
$("[id$=DocumentLink]")[0].href = LinkText;
```

And since your matching an exact ID, just use `$("#DocumentLink")`

Comment: Because it's the ID, you can just query by doing: $("#DocumentLink") instead,which will be more efficient.

Comment: @BrianMains -- Good point, didnt realize the ID was an exact match, updated the answer.

Comment: thanks, could I ask what more a jquery object has besides the HTML element?

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
$("#DocumentLink").attr('href', LinkText);
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery object doesn't have `href` property. You are defining a property for the jQuery object which doesn't affect the `href` property of the HTMLElement object in the jQuery collection. You could use the `attr` or the `prop` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

set the attr of the link.

```
$("[id$=DocumentLink]").attr("href", LinkText);
```

i think it would be much easier to use JS and `innerHTML`.